# How to POST data in flask, and get it using an Ajax call?

Tags: ajax, python-3.x, post, flask, get

I am creating a flask web app, and I want to display some information that I have scraped with BS4 on an external file. I have already imported that file's function and called the data, my question is what is my error here? I want to be able to POST this data using Flask, and then call the data with an Ajax call so I can manipulate my HTML page.

I have tried many different ways of doing this, including using `methods = ['GET', 'POST]`, and changing my `_get_data():` function

Flask app file

```
#Import dependencies
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd

import requests

import json
from scrape import *

from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify, request, escape, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)

#Get out list to post
data = scrape_data()
headers = data_headers()

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/_get_data', methods = ['GET','POST'])
def _get_data():
    data = request.form.getlist('data[]')
    print(data)
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug = True)
```

HTML File

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
    <meta charset = "utf-8">

    <title>NBA Data Web App</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" crossorigin = "anonymous"></script>
    <button id = "searchBtn"> Search </button>

    <div id = "response"></div>

    <script type = "text/javascript">
        var headers = 
        $('button#searchBtn').click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/_get_data",
                data : {'data': dataList},
                success: function(resp) {
                    $('div#response').append(resp.data)
                }
            });
        });
        console.log(dataList);


    </script>

    <ul>
        {% for elem in dataList %}

            <li>{{elem}}</li>

        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: CODE I AM CURRENTLY WORKING WITH

Answer (score 0):

The question is how to send a list of python data to javascript, via AJAX.

Here is a possible approach:

**PYTHON'S SIDE**:

```
# Other imports

from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify, request, escape, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)

#Get out list to post
data = scrape_data()
headers = data_headers()

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/_get_data', methods = ['POST'])
def get_data():
    return jsonify({'data': data})

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug = True)
```

**HTML/JAVASCRIPT:**

```
<body>

    <button id = "searchBtn"> Search </button>

    <div id = "response"></div>

    <script type = "text/javascript">
        $('button#searchBtn').click(function() {
            var data_list;
            $.post('/_get_data', {
            }).done(function(response) {
                data_list = response['data'];
                console.log(data_list);
                //If your list is received correctly, you will have to write a javascript loop to retrieve one by one the data and display them on your page
            }).fail(function() {
                alert("request failed");
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: The data is a list, does that make a difference

Comment: Either way, I got "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404"

Comment: If this code does not work, try this instead: `data = request.form.getlist('data[]')`

Comment: Thank you, I had fixed the 404 error myself just before you posted this. The problem is, the response doesn’t update with my data, and I logged what it was trying to post and what I logged showed up as “undefined”

Comment: So for me to understand, when you make a `console.log(dataList);` you get **undefined**?

Comment: I updated the code I am working with. When I run the code shown, I get "dataList undefined"

Comment: The undefined type is a javascript type. if you get this message from the python side, it means the problem comes from javascript. Your `dataList` is currently undefined. Try a `console.log(dataList);` to see if your list contains anything.

Comment: Do you mean ```print(dataList)``` on the python side? @Tobin

Comment: Not on the python side but javascript. I just looked at your code and realize that you did not declare the variable `dataList` in your Javascript code. It is for this reason that it is undefined. Try to declare it and give it a real list. Example: `var dataList = [1, 2, 3, 4]`.

Comment: That’s the thing haha, the the data (which is a list in python) I want to display in JavaScript FROM my Flask app. I just don’t know how to connect the two properly with a post request

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201738/discussion-between-tobin-and-robert-smith).

Comment: I sent you a message